# Why does my enemy keep teleporting to the origin in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started making a game. For whatever reason, the enemy continuously teleports to the origin for no reason. Here is my code so far;

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.5f;
    public Transform target;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(target);
        transform.position = transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I have the target object assigned to the player. Someone please help because I can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: we're missing a fair amount of code, you might want to share MonoBehaviour as well so we know what your code actually does. Also running in debug mode might help you discover where the bug actually occurs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `transform.forward` is a result axis, not a specific location, and gives you numbers around -1 to 1. To fix that just try:

```
transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
```